# Exception not caught when thrown by RESTSharp

Tags: c#, .net, exception, restsharp

I'm using RestSharp to communicate with a REST-Server and wrote a small wrapper function for the call

```
private T Get<T>(string restAdress) where T : new()
{
    try
    {
        // throw new Exception(); // This one is caught
        IRestClient restClient = new RestClient(settings.Value.HostToConnect).UseSerializer(new JsonNetSerializer()); // (1)
        RestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest(restAdress);
        IRestResponse<T> result = restClient.Get<T>(restRequest); // (2)
        return result.Data;
    }
    catch (Exception e) // debugger wont stop here
    {
        // debugger wont stop here too
        // code within this block is not executed
    }

    return null; // (3)
}
```

Since I want to use the Newtonsoft-Attributes I give in a custom (de)serializer (1).

```
    public class JsonNetSerializer : IRestSerializer
    {
        public string Serialize(object obj) =>
            JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);

        public string Serialize(RestSharp.Parameter bodyParameter) =>
            JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bodyParameter.Value);

        public T Deserialize<T>(IRestResponse response) =>
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response.Content); // (4)

        public string[] SupportedContentTypes { get; } =
        {
            "application/json", "text/json", "text/x-json", "text/javascript", "*+json"
        };

        public string ContentType { get; set; } = "application/json";

        public DataFormat DataFormat { get; } = DataFormat.Json;
    }
```

When calling the REST service and trying to get the result (2) an `Exception` is thrown if the deserialization fails (4). But the `Exception` is not caught by the `try-catch` block. I tried to debug but after throwing the debugger goes on in line (3), the `catch` and the logging withing the catch is never executed. The debugger won't even stop at the `catch (Exception e)` it goes straight from (4) to (3).

[image]
(Sorry for not english, the title of the window says "Exception User-Unhandled")

Can anyone explain this behaviour to me?

Comment: Did you cleanup your project and rebuild (Rebuild all is not the same as a full cleanup)? This typically happens when there is some mismatch between the executed assemblies and what the debugger tries to match

Comment: @grek40 I did, multiple times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whats happening here is an interesting setting of the debugger, another example would be this [closed bug report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/75445/visual-studio-displays-exception-user-unhandled-bu.html). When the debugger reaches the point the exception is thrown it will break, causing the behaviour you experienced.

If you uncheck the exception setting "Break when this exception type is user-unhandled" in the dialog, you should be able to reach your catch block, as the debugger no longer breaks the execution as soon as the specified exception is thrown.

In your case you find that option under "Ausnahmeeinstellungen".

Answer (score 3):

I am maintaining RestSharp, so I hope I can answer this.

RestSharp doesn't throw on deserialisation by default. If you look at the code, deserialisation happens in the private `IRestResponse<T> Deserialize<T>(IRestRequest request, IRestResponse raw)` method of `RestClient`.

When RestSharp can't deserialise the response, it creates an error response. You get the response status set to `Error` and the exception is put into the `ErrorException` property of the response object, along with the exception message that gets to the `ErrorMessage` of the response.

It is still possible to tell RestSharp to throw on deserialisation if you assign the `FailOnDeserialization` property of the `RestClient` instance to `true`.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I tried to set the ``FailOnDeserialization`` to true and threw an exception in ``JsonNetSerializer.Deserialize<T>(...)`` but the exception is still caught by RestSharp and my catch was useless like before. Given the source code I also cant see a rethrow

Comment: That is strange. Do you mind opening an issue in the RestSharp repository?

Comment: Done. Thank you although the other answer was technically the right one